# handler doesnt work in android

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I've this code.

i'm trying to understand how the handlers works with threads. before of several tries i gave a code without errors, but it doesn't works =(

```
public class Principal extends ActionBarActivity {


TextView TEXTO;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
    TEXTO=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TEXTO);




    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

                 android.os.Message msg = new android.os.Message();
                 msg.obj="FUNCIONO";

                 vistaHandler.handleMessage(msg);// i tried with send message and neither works
        }
    }).start();


}
Handler vistaHandler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        TEXTO.setText(msg.toString()+"");
    }
};
```

}

if it works, it would print "HOLA" , but It doesn't do it =(

i think i'm doing all right but nothing.

Comment: it would print `HOLA`! Why?

Comment: "HOLA" was a example, i just want to know why the handlers isn't working =S

Comment: It is working, why do you think your example dose not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your message this way (This can be simplified based on your needs of course):

```
Message msgObj = vistaHandler.obtainMessage();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", yourMessage);
// Add any other stuff you want to the bundle
msgObj.setData(bundle);
vistaHandler.sendMessage(msgObj);
```

Then in your `handleMessage(Message msg)` do this:

```
String response = msg.getData().getString("message");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `Message.obj`, and then you are calling `toString` on `Message` not on `obj`.

Change your

```
`TEXTO.setText(msg.toString()+"");`
```

to

```
TEXTO.setText((String)msg.obj+"");
```